# University affiliations are notified when they are inserted?

Tags: independent-researcher, affiliation

I'm having trouble inserting affiliation. My master's dissertation has been completed and I have graduated from university. I want to publish an article out of my dessertaion however my supervisor does not approve since my research has political factors and he does not want to get involved. If I affilaion to my university without mentioning my supervisor's name, there is a chance that my university won't approve it since the supervisor's name has to be included in the article. The university has the right to claim its' right if I don't put my university as affiliation and put independent researcher, since that was actually my affiliation at the time. How should I proceed?
Does my university have a chance of not getting notified if I put its' name?

Comment: I doubt a journal will do any checking of your affiliation listing.  (Just make sure the email address you provide actually works to contact you.)

Comment: Thank you. What about my university? Is it notified after publication?